# Wordpress Bulk Edit deletes custom taxonomy value

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy that I am "auto" assigning a value whenever a post is saved. It is saving the first letter of the post_title so I can use in a custom A to Z list (similar to this: http://geekgirllife.com/alphabetical-index-of-posts-in-wordpress/)

I have registered the taxonomy in my theme's functions.php as well as the auto assign function. Everything is working, when create/edit/save a post it adds the first letter of the post title into this custom tax.

However when I bulk edited some posts from the default WP bulk actions functionality, it overwrites the custom taxonomy value for the posts being edited.

My question is, is there a way to exclude a custom taxonomy from the bulk edit action in WP? Or a way bulk edit action will treat a custom tax as "no change" rather than update it w/ empty value?

Register Taxonomy code:

```
function atoz_tax() {
    register_taxonomy( 'atoz',array (
        0 => 'page',
    ),
    array( 'hierarchical' => false,
        'label' => 'atoz',
        'show_ui' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
    ) );
}
add_action('init', 'atoz_tax');
```

Code that auto saves to taxonomy on save:

```
function atoz_save_first_letter( $post_id ) {
  // verify if this is an auto save routine.
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
      return $post_id;

  //Check permissions
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

  // find and save the data
  $taxonomy = 'atoz';

  //set term as first letter of post title, lower case
  wp_set_object_terms($post_id,strtolower(substr($_POST['post_title'], 0, 1)), $taxonomy);

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'atoz_save_first_letter' );
```

Comment: Does question on WordPress Development Stack Exchange address your situation? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33755/how-to-prevent-custom-fields-from-being-cleared-during-a-bulk-edit